# Fresco : Listview showing wrong image when fast scrolling

Tags: android, performance, listview, fresco

I have custom listview. In listview contain 200 items. When i am scrolling fast from top to bottom Or bottom to top listview showing wrong image. If i am scrolling slowly then its work fine.

**SimpleDraweeView in XML :**

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/fake_image_list_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/note_list_item_height"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

**Set Image URI to SimpleDraweeView :**

```
GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = setHierarchyForDraweeView(mImageView, 300);
   hierarchy.setPlaceholderImage(new AsyncColorDrawable(context.getResources()));
   hierarchy.setFailureImage(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.broken_image_black));
   ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath/*local path*/)))
           .setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(width, height))
           .setLocalThumbnailPreviewsEnabled(true)
           .build();
   DraweeController draweeController = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
           .setImageRequest(imageRequest)
           .setOldController(mImageView.getController())
           .setAutoPlayAnimations(false)
           .build();
   mImageView.setController(draweeController);
```

**SetHierarchyForDraweeView Function :**

```
private GenericDraweeHierarchy setHierarchyForDraweeView(SimpleDraweeView draweeView, int duration) {
    if (draweeView != null) {
        if (draweeView.getHierarchy() == null) {
            GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder builder = new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(mContext.getResources());
            GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = builder
                    .setFadeDuration(duration)
                    .setPlaceholderImage(new AsyncColorDrawable(mContext.getResources()))
                    .setFailureImage(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.broken_image_black))
                    .build();
            draweeView.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
        } else {
            GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = draweeView.getHierarchy();
            hierarchy.setFadeDuration(duration);
            return hierarchy;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**AsyncColorDrawable Class :**

```
private class AsyncColorDrawable extends ColorDrawable {
    public AsyncColorDrawable(Resources res) {
        super(res.getColor(R.color.application_container_background_color));
    }
}
```

If i did anything wrong please figure it out. Thanks for advance.

Answer (score -1):

For this you need to use Universal Image Loader. It is an smart and powerful library that helps in loading, caching and displaying images on Android. Have a look at [this](http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-library-in-android)

Comment: Right now i am using fresco library. If i am using other library its work fine. why its occur in this library ?